# What's the latest solution for rounded corners?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

Can anyone tell me the the latest solution for implementing rounded corners with DIV tags?  Is the PNG corner images still the best cross-browser solution?  Is Jquery the best approach?  How is everyone approaching the rounded corners problem?

Many thanks.

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal solution at the moment is to use:

```
selector {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

That will work in "all" modern browsers including IE9, see: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

By *far* the best workaround for older versions of IE is to [use CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/):

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-8
> capable of rendering several of the
> most useful CSS3 decoration features.
>
> PIE currently has full or partial
> support for the following CSS3
> features:
>
> • **border-radius**
> • box-shadow
> • border-image
> • multiple background images
> • linear-gradient as background image

As you can see, you also get support for more CSS3 eye candy

Comment: I sure wish I'd written this answer sooner.

Answer (score 6):

For most browsers, CSS3 provides a way.

http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

```
.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

No need for images anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you must support **IE8** and earlier, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb250413) are a number of ways to accomplish rounded corners.

According to that Microsoft page:

> Windows **Internet Explorer 9**
>   supports adding rounded corners to
>   elements using the border-radius
>   properties.

It also suggests these pages which claim to be updated:

[25 Rounded Corners Techniques with CSS](http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/)

[CSS Rounded Corners 'Roundup'](http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000044.php)

[Rounded Corners](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Rounded_Corners)

Without having read all of these many approaches, I'd hazard a guess that there is no universal best solution at the moment. Until we can assume that pretty much all of our visitors have CSS3-compliant browsers, you have to make some choices.