# Html CSS round corner help stacking elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an round corner with an image. But I get get on top of the other images.

My code:

```
<div style="width:468;height:60; border:1px solid #cccccc;border-right:none;position:relative;">
<span style="background: url("../images/showkontopleft.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; width: 5px; height: 5px; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; display: block;"></span>
<a target="_blank" href="/link/8" style="float:left;display:inline;">
<img style="width: 468px; height: 60px; border: 0pt none; display: block;" src="http://dk.orvillemedia.com/ads/banners/514/468x60.jpg" alt="468x60">
</a>
</div>
```

Problem:
[image]

Comment: What about z-index http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I have tried but it didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give height to div and add style position:absolute to span.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your specific problem is, but you should be aware that the argument to `url()` isn't quoted. Your reference should be:

```
url(../images/showkontopleft.png)
```

Also, why are you putting a background-image on an inline element? What do you hope to gain from that?

Comment: It was stackoverflow that quoted some of the css.

Answer (score 2):

Do not stress yourself over image rounded corners, just use css, http://bit.ly/O2Fl

I know, I know, "What about IE?". Leave it alone. It deserves the jagged corners.

Just my take.

Comment: For IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170177/whats-the-latest-solution-for-rounded-corners/6170385#6170385

Comment: Exactly, let them have jagged corners. They deserve them. Don't worry, I will not tell them.

Answer (score 0):

So You want to have an image on other image. How about

```
<img class="corner" src="corner.png" style="position:relative; z-index:1" />
<img class="main-image" src="main.jpg" style="position:relative; margin-top:-10px z-index:0" />
```

?